# gnuplot unable to output images

Tags: file, debugging, gnuplot

I tried the following code and expected an image sequence to be produced, but when I ran it, no files were generated.

```
reset
set terminal png size 640, 480
set dummy x

do for [i=1:12] {
    set output sprintf('sumofsinusoids.%03.0f.png', i)
    plot sin(x)
}
```

I suspect that the plot function is creating the problem.

Comment: Works perfectly well for me on Debian Wheezy / gnuplot 4.6

Comment: @vaettchen I have gnuplot 5.0. I think some of the codes are too old.

Comment: Can't test myself but looking at some gnuplot 5 samples, adding `set output` as the last command before the closing `}` might help ("flushing the output channel")

Comment: @vaettchen That would cause the last output file to be corrupted. (i = 12)

Comment: No, a final `set output` would flush the last image, so that it is actually completed. But that is only relevant in interactive mode or if one wants to run other programm on the output file from within the gnuplot script

Comment: I just tested this example with gnuplot 5.0 and it works as expected, i.e., generates a sequence of 12 images

Comment: I tested your example with gnuplot 5.0 on linuxmint, and works fine ;)

Comment: @vagoberto For some reason just a simple reboot causes gnuplot to work again.